# prefix testmain on multiple instance

Tags: go, testing

I am using TestMain to test multiple implementation of the same interface

```
func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    setup1()
    code = m.Run()
    if code != 0 {
        os.exit(code)
    }

    setup2()
    code = m.Run()
    if code != 0 {
        os.exit(code)
    }
}
```

If I then get an error in a test, it is difficult to know which implementation generated the failure

In T subtests, you run like this :

```
t.run("test name", testfunc)
```

is there a way to do something to prefix the Main tests

```
m.Run("name") // intuitively what I should be able to do
```

EDIT : Adding some background because it looks like people are not seeing what it is about

```
// MyInterface is implemented multiple time, but we expect the same behavior for any implementation
type IMyInterface interface {
    SomeMethod()
    SomeOtherMethod()
}

var (
    implUnderTest IMyInterface // is referred to in every tests
)

// There are many test files with many tests run for each implementation
func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    for _, impl := range []IMyInterface {&Impl1{}, &Impl2{}, &Impl3{}} {
        implUnderTest = impl
        code := m.Run()
        if code != 0 {
            os.exit(code)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `os.Exit(code)` terminates the app, the code after that (the second test run) won't run.

Comment: yes in reality I got if code != 0 exit, I type the example in SO directly

Comment: In the standard library they just call `fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "error: %v\n", err)` followed by a os.Exit as you do

Comment: `TestMain` and its `testing.M` parameter are the context of the entire test run. They should have nothing to do with individual tests. Multiple tests should be in different test functions or different subtests, which are already distinguishable in results.

Comment: Like I said in another comment, I don't see the point in telling me I shouldn't do that. We've got 14 files with roughly 700 line of tests each. We are not going to copy them and maintain two copy of the exact same tests. This pattern also ensure that any future implementation of the interface will be easy to test.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `m.Run()` multiple times seems like an anti-pattern. Create multiple tests that have different setups and name them accordingly. AFAIK there is no `m.Run("name")`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but you are missing the point. I run the exact same test in two implementation of the same interface. the purpose is to be able to test any implementation regardless of how it implements it. I have many good reasons to do that in the context of my project.

Comment: If you have an interface to test, you can write a function `testInterface(t *testing.T, i interface{}, n string)` that accepts this interface and call `testInterface` multiple times. Still no need to call `m.Run()` multiple times. Here is an [example](https://play.golang.org/p/tXTG2SzvetU). There isn't even a need for a `TestMain` anymore.

Comment: I see what you mean, and I agree it would work, but it would need to contain a call to every tests (the biggest interface currently have 14 test files with on average 7-8 test function each). It would need to be updated every time I create a new test file with new tests.
Another things is that the example testA_Call methods doesn't have a test signature, and would have godoc generated for it  which we want to avoid.

Comment: If you wish to discuss this further, I would be happy to have a chat with you privately, to avoid adding more comments here

Answer (score 0):

I am still looking for a better solution, until then I'm doing something like the following

```
func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    setup1()
    code = m.Run()
    if code != 0 {
        log.Println("failed on implementation 1")
        os.exit(code)
    }

    setup2()
    code = m.Run()
    if code != 0 {
        log.Println("failed on implementation 2")
        os.exit(code)
    }
}
```